# After upgrade Magento 2.4.1 not redirect on success page after place order

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, magento2.4.1

After upgrade Magento 2.4.1
We are getting issues on the checkout page.
Redirect on back to cart page after place an order instead of the success page.

Order look fine in the admin panel.
And not get any error at the frontend but the only issue is not redirecting on the success page after place an order.

Already tried with basic Magento command like an upgrade, deploy, flush cache etc...

Comment: this sounds like a behavior that a 3rd party module would introduce. can you disable your 3rd party extensions and see if the issue is still reproducing?

Comment: Many extensions are there. And not get any error related this on log or frontend.

Comment: are you using a custom payment method in this scenario?

Comment: no, but trying with COD, Or Bank Payment..

Answer (score 1):

Temporary Find Solution to Disabling Order Email.
After Disable Order Email from admin checkout will redirect on the success page.

Sales -> Sales Emails -> Order

So the issue is related to Order Email.

Comment: Thanks brother
Its working now !! (Y)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue due to some customization for email-related.

For permanent solutions, I would like to suggest you disable third-party or custom extensions one by one and then test.